# Divs not aligned

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a row of divs that are not aligned. Each div is displayed inline-block, but the one that has 2 lines of text is out of line with the rest of the row.

```css
.stopHoriz {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .8em;
}
.stopVertical {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .8em;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-right: 30px; vertical-align:top">
  <div class="stopHoriz">Amusement</div>
  <div class="stopHoriz">State Park</div>
  <div class="stopHoriz">Zoo</div>
  <div class="stopHoriz">History</div>
  <div class="stopHoriz">Marine Encounters</div>
  <div class="stopHoriz">Onset</div>
  <div class="stopHoriz">Museum</div>
  <div class="stopHoriz">Beaches</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `vertical-align:top` in your `.stopHoriz` divs to align them.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rDYM5/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following CSS class if it seems helpful to you.

```
.stopHoriz
{
display: inline;
border: 1px solid #000;
font-size: .8em;
padding: 10px;
}
```

So that it will take up space as needed rather than you fixing the width and height.

Answer (score 0):

set the width to 100px. It has to do with the width you have set. The word 'Marine encounter' does not fit in your specified width. Apart from that you can also use `'vertical-align':top`. There are many solutions. It depends on what you use.